# Using ADB to edit Android Kindle Fire launcher default

Tags: default, adb, kindle-fire

I installed a launcher (syndicateapps ICS 4.0) on my rooted Kindle Fire; like an idiot I ticked 'Set to Default' only to get "The application ICS 4.0 Launcher (process android.process.acore) has stopped unexpectedly".

Force close just loops round to the same screen.

I can access my KF with adb but haven't able to find the file I need to edit which will remove the default.

Advice appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue... here is a solution using a windows machine.

Refer to this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JqKZLMaRSgc) and the back links in the video description to setup the Kindle Fire Utility.
Once installed -- if not already, open kindle Fire Utility folder, you should see a file called 'run' inside. Double click on that file, you should see a command prompt window display.

Type in '7' for going into the 'Extras' options.

From there type in '2' which "Installs Google Apps / Go Launcher.

Once all the packages are installed you will gain access to your home screen to remove the launcher you have and use your fire again.

Comment: Brilliant - very many thanks.  (Sorry, haven't got enough Reputation to increment the counter)